# $∀$ quantifier in Epsilon delta definition of limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

given $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a} f\left( x \right) = L$$

means by Epsilon Delta definition :

∀ $ε>0$, ∃ $δ>0$ such that  $0<|x−a|<δ$ implies $|(f(x)-L|< ε$

my question is about ∀ $ε>0$ , how we can make sure that any picked distance form L will be defined in the range of function ? I looking at ∀ $ε>0$ as "Choose any distance you want from L " and i think this is true for a function with range $\left(-\infty \:,\:\infty \:\right)$.

I mean there is no such a restriction to this in pierce definition or we just assume that $ε$ must be a very small number.

[image: Epsilon defined as disatce not in the range of f(x)]

used function :
$f(x)=\left\{x>2:2+\frac{2}{\left(x-1\right)^2}\right\}$

Comment: The function $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $0$ even though for any $\epsilon > 0$, the negative values will always be missing from the horizontal strip defined by $\epsilon$. However, the definition never requires that such values exist - it simply states that for any positive $\epsilon$, there exists a positive $\delta$... etc. (it helps me to read the definition very literally). $\epsilon$ isn't bound by the range, as @Kavi Rama Murthy said.

Comment: $(L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon) $ is not supposed to be a part of range of $f$ rather its somewhat reverse. We should have $f((a-\delta, a+\delta) \setminus \{a\}) \subseteq (L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh -  aha , then with this we ensure that as $x$ approach $a$ in  $|x-a|<δ $ $f(x)$ approach $L$ in $|f(x)-L|<ϵ$ in a side of function that exist. Is this the way should i think ?

Comment: Yes that's the idea. The definition of limit makes this idea precise/unambiguous.

Comment: No doubt Ammar Bamhdi spent time thinking about this and their work will pay off with really understanding the concept. (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the condition holds when $\epsilon$ is small, say when $\epsilon <r$. Then, for any $\epsilon >0$ take $\epsilon_1 \in (0, \min \{r, \epsilon\})$ and find $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon_1$ for $0 <|x-a| <\delta$. This is possible because $\epsilon_1 <r$. But now we also have $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$. So it is possible to find a $\delta$ for any $ \epsilon >0$. This has nothing to do with the range of $f$.

Comment: OK I get the idea, but I'm wondering why would this definition put $∀$ we can simply say given $ϵ >0$ ? is this quantifier indicate some thing?

Comment: @AmmarBamhdi Yes, $\forall \epsilon >0$ is same as given $\epsilon >0$.

Answer (score 1):

An example picture/graph helps to 'bring to life' Paramanand Singh's comment.

When 'warming up' to an epsilon/delta, you can play around with real numbers.

Suppose $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a} f\left( x \right) = L$

with $a = 2$ and $L = 3$. so that you are looking at

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 2} f\left( x \right) = 3$$

for some function $f$.

If you are presented with an actual number $\varepsilon = .75$, your analysis shows that with $\delta =.5$,

$$ f\left(\,(\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2}) \setminus \{2\}\,\right) \subset (\frac{9}{4},\frac{15}{4})$$

You can graph  the corresponding $\varepsilon/\delta$ rectangle:

[image]

and you can thereby 'control the fluctuations' of $f$ by 'keeping its action inside that rectangle'.

If you are given another actual number, say $\varepsilon = .25$, you can 'accept the challenge' once again, and come up with a $\delta$ and the 'action inside rectangle'.

You now decide to accept an *arbitrary symbol* $\varepsilon \gt 0$, finding a $\delta$ such that

$$ f\left(\,(2-\delta,2+\delta) \setminus \{2\}\,\right) \subset (3-\varepsilon, 3+\varepsilon)$$

In general (removing the picture), $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a} f\left( x \right) = L$ if for every $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exist a $\delta \gt 0$ such that

$$\tag 1 f\left< \;(a-\delta,a+\delta) \setminus \{a\}\;\right> \subset (L-\varepsilon, L+\varepsilon)$$

Comment: @CopyPastelt , hi bro, thanks for helping, I was thinking that any chosen epsilon must follow $f(x) ∈ |f(x)-L|<ε$ but i was wrong. an example function $f(x)=x^2$ and how we study the limit in term of EP-DL definition around 0  since there is no such $f(x)$ value in $-y$ axis as **J_P** said above. any way, it turns out that epsilon has nothing to do with range of $f(x)$ instead we looking in $x$ values range that apply  $$\tag 1 f\left< \;(a-\delta,a+\delta) \setminus \{a\}\;\right> \subset (L+\varepsilon, L-\varepsilon)$$ and by this, it is convenient to consider choosing any positive epsilon

Comment: @AmmarBamhdi When you learn the definition of $f$ being continuous at a point $a$, you will see that is all about, with $\varepsilon \gt 0$ specified, being able to  control  the outputs of $f$ to be within an $\varepsilon$ distance from $f(a) = L$ by finding a $\delta \gt 0$ and only applying $f$ to numbers within a $\delta$ distance from $a$, ($f$ is defined at $a$)